# Making Custom MenuItems in Java (Color)

Tags: java, menuitem

I am trying to make a JMenu at the top of an Application, that has Custom MenuItems, such that the menu items are not the usual plain words. I have an idea in which on one side of each MenuItem there is a color or theme, and on the other side, a color representing that them.

I have been unable in my research and coding to find a way to make a sort of custom MeneItem like this in a Java Application.

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a picture to go with them words...

Comment: I've done this before by overriding paintComponent in JMenuItem. Edit: Have a look at this: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/03/how_to_create_c.html

Comment: Sorry but you need to use a photo hosting site and link the image. You dont have enough rep to post pictures here, and I don't see how your file system path is going to help us out.

Comment: I assume that you can use a `JMenuItem` with an `Icon` instead of text (particularly, an `ImageIcon`). Have a look at this yellow, star-shaped thing in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html ...